# Creating a task in a project with curl

Tags: asana

I want to create a task in a specific project. But when I post it, I get below error.

```
{"errors":[{"message":"projects: [0]: Not an ID: [object Object]"}]}
```

I posted using curl and below is the data. (Typo updated)

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u 2BC1ks3G.OaTb9R00HSdIQkF0aRottLj: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks --data '{
    "data": {
        "assignee": 123,
        "followers": [
            {
                "id": 456
            }
        ],
        "name": "Hello, world! ",
        "notes": "How are you today?",
        "projects": [{"id": 1000001}],
        "workspace": 7762331677906
    }        
 }'
```

Comment: Is the curly brace at the end of the line with "projects" in the original, or a copy-and-pase issue?

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo while I am posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `"projects": [{"id": 1000001}]` you actually just need `"projects": [1000001]` - we have a task for ourselves to fix the way this is mapped (since the form you have is the correct *output* format, and they should really be consistent). Of course the same format should work both ways! We just have a billion (numeric accuracy may be hyperbolic) other things we're building in the API so I'm not sure when that will happen.

Sorry for the inconvenience, and I hope that helps in the meantime!